# Building custom PUT/PATCH request: No Route matches [GET]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am attempting to use the PATCH/PUT actions on the method on controller:

```
def specialClickThrough
        # Incriment click
        clickIncrimentBudgetReduce = "UPDATE `campaigns` 
                                        SET clicks = clicks + 1
                                        , budget = (budget - bid_price)
                                        , is_active = CASE
                                                      WHEN (budget - bid_price) > 0.0
                                                        THEN 1
                                                      ELSE 0
                                                      END   
                                        WHERE id = " + params[:campaign_id].to_s  

        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(clickIncrimentBudgetReduce)
    end
```

When typing: `localhost:3000/specialClickThrough/27` into the browser it returns that: `No route matches [GET] "/specialClickThrough/27"`, even though there clearly is one as:

```
match '/specialClickThrough/:campaign_id', to: 'requests#specialClickThrough', via: 'put'
```

**UPDATE**

I tried in the postman chrome extension but still nothing:

[image]

From the docs it notes to simply set the request type as the one required. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Maybe, the route is correct. But, your HTTP request is wrong. 
Yout don't have `GET /specialClickThrough/:id` route. That's why `No route matches [GET] "/specialClickThrough/27"` returned.
You should add `<%= link_to 'special click through`, special_click_through_path, method: :put %>` and click it.

Comment: Try to look at what routes are actually available. To do so, you can do `bin/rake routes` (rails 4)

Comment: @Edward When I pass the route, it does appear as being available, I just don't know how to properly call it. How do I properly call a PUT route, without using GET?

Comment: @Sauron See my answer below

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `via: 'put'` option, the GET won't work...
So, how are you trying to perform the PUT request?
try using [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782198/how-to-do-a-put-request-with-curl) or [postman](http://www.getpostman.com/docs) maybe...
The route is well defined. The problem is you are doing a GET instead a PUT request.

Comment: I updated the question to clarify. But what I am doing is using rails as a webservice and API, and wish to be able to access the URL: `localhost:3000/specialClickThrough/27`, that would then complete the action in the method specialClickThrough. How can I enable that?

Comment: If you try to access `localhost:3000/specialClickThrough/27` from your browser, you will perform a GET not a PUT. You cant perform a PUT just putting the url in your browser. As I said, I recommend you to use Postman (chrome plugin) and select the "PUT option" to perform this kind of actions. Maybe you can do a link as @shoji said in the comment to do a quick check. But you need a better tool (curl, postman) in order to test/use your API more easily

Comment: I tried using Postman and setting to "put", but still nothing, see updated question

Comment: You are getting now a **422 status**, not a **404** related with `No route matches [GET] "/specialClickThrough/27"`. It's a new error. So, the PUT it's working.

Comment: I think you don't have a single question, you have multiple issues. You need to make an effort to solve the problem and make more accurate questions.

Answer (score 0):

In your postman, it appears to be response code `422` which usually comes from a parameter validation error. Of course, because you are hitting the endpoint with no parameters passed in while your route requires a `campaign_id` (For a PUT request, you need to pass parameters as data, instead of encoded url like GET.)

When you send a put request, make sure that `campaign_id` is available. (For example, in your postman, try type in `campaign_id` in the `key` field right above the `send` button and some value. It should give you something other than a `422` depending on your implementation)

Comment: I have done that, setting campaign_id in key...but it still notes 422 OK

Comment: are you making a request to `/specialClickThrough/27`? if so, you should be hitting `/specialClickThrough` instead