# QNetworkAccessManager::put is too slow

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager

I'm writing small programm like [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/ab.html) to test my small rest web service. My app can produce about 200-300 request per second, but ab could about 8k-9k (on the same machine). After small investigation I found the issue - if I use empty QByteArray it works fast. Here is code:

```
// simplesender.h
#ifndef SIMPLESENDER_H
#define SIMPLESENDER_H
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QQueue>

#include <QObject>

class SimpleSender : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SimpleSender(QObject *parent = 0)
    {
        connect(&qnam, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &SimpleSender::slFinished);
        url = QUrl("http://localhost:8080");
        m_in_progress = 0;
        sendHttpRequest();
    }

private slots:
    void slFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)
    {
        QByteArray b = reply->readAll();
        Q_UNUSED(b);
        m_in_progress--;
        sendHttpRequest();
        reply->deleteLater();
    }

private:
    int m_in_progress;
    QUrl url;

    QNetworkAccessManager qnam;
    void sendHttpRequest()
    {
        while (m_in_progress < 10) {
            QNetworkRequest r(url);
            QByteArray bb = QByteArray("t"); // with this line 200 r/s
            //QByteArray bb; // with this line 8k r/s
            qnam.put(r, bb);

            m_in_progress++;
        }
    }

};

#endif // SIMPLESENDER_H
```

in main.cpp

```
#include <simplesender.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    SimpleSender hs(&a);
    return a.exec();
}
```

My question is how to improve performance.

Comment: I do not ask for code review. It is small example that show the issue.

Comment: your title says that `QNetworkAccessManager::put` is too slow. Are other request types (`QNetworkAccessManager::get`, `QNetworkAccessManager::post`, ..) faster for you?

Comment: get is fast enough. put with empty QByteArray also fast.

Comment: Make a debug build of Qt, run it under a profiler, and see why it happens. To improve performance, you likely have to fix the Qt bug that causes this problem. What exact Qt version, compiler version and platform this is?

Comment: I test with Qt 5.5.1 and 5.2.1, x64, Gentoo and Ubuntu. I profiled it and it looks like my code spend about 5-6%. I will try with debug Qt library.

Comment: See where it's blocking for I/O. Also see if this has anything to do with Qt. You'd expect same behavior when you use e.g. [curl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13782198/1329652) from the command line and time the same number of executions.