# How to update values with php curl

Tags: php, curl, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am working on google spreadsheet and want to update data that I want. I read this [article](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) and update the data successful on its console. Now I want to update data with `PHP curl` and I am a little bit confuse for these options

1. `valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED`
2. `"majorDimension": "COLUMNS"`

When I entered my desired values in above **Article** console editor its update data successfully and give me following results

**Request**

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/**************F9NM/values/A4:G4?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "majorDimension": "COLUMNS",
 "values": [
  [
   "myemail@mail.com"
  ],
  [
   "First Name"
  ],
  [
   "Last Name"
  ],
  [
   "Mobile"
  ],
  [
   "URL"
  ],
  [
   "US"
  ],
  [
   "54654654654"
  ]
 ]
}
```

**Response**

```
Cache-Control:  private
Content-Encoding:  gzip
Content-Length:  143
Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date:  Sat, 08 Oct 2016 09:34:11 GMT
Server:  ESF
Vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer

{
 "spreadsheetId": "******************F9NM",
 "updatedRange": "Sheet1!A4:G4",
 "updatedRows": 1,
 "updatedColumns": 7,
 "updatedCells": 7
}
```

So my confusion is that how can i put my values (that I want to update) in this `USER_ENTERED` and how can I set `majorDimension": "COLUMNS` in php curl api link.

I searched a lot and read many articles about `Update google api spreadsheet` but I get nothing helpful or use full

> **Here is my code that I want to try in php file:**

```
$curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/*********F9NM/values/A4:G4?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&key=******************38");
    //curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');

    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading from this cURL guide from [11. Custom Request Elements](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html), You can use POST/PUT method by using cURL -D then add the values.

> "It should be noted that curl selects which methods to use on its own depending on what action to ask for. -d will do POST.."

There's also a sample provided in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782198/how-to-do-a-put-request-with-curl) that might be of help:

curl -X PUT -d arg=val -d arg2=val2 localhost:8080